# How can i play mp3 files in Ubuntu 14.04 lts without internet?

Tags: mp3

I can't play mp3 files in Ubuntu. So give me the best answer for this question

Comment: if i got you right this will help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the Restricted Formats?

Open up terminal ctrl+alt+t and paste

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Then press Enter and type your password and pres enter again.

Comment: I tried but it replies that: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-ex.   So what should i do?

Comment: What happens if you go to apt://ubuntu-restricted-extras in your browser?                                                                                                       Also did you paste the entire line it appears you only pasted up to the "ubuntu-restricted-ex"  part.    try the entire command.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, Fluendo develops Gstreamer plugins and codecs which can be downloaded to a flash drive and installed. They make money from many of their software packages but they offer an mp3 codec for free. It is called the Oneplay mp3 decoder. Since Ubuntu is based on Debian, I suggest you get the .deb file for either x86 or 64 bit architecture.

http://www.oneplaydirect.com/oneplay/oneplay-mp3-decoder/